# AWS security group creation fails 1 about out of every 30 times code is executed with java aws sdk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I have AWS SDK Java code that usually works to create a security group however in perhaps 1 in 30 times, the security group seems to be created without error but then does not actually exist. The following code executes without exception and the log writes out the security group ID as normal as if if was created, however the security group is not actually created.

```
Security group created: [sg-0da6057afd04b52a2]


    try {
        CreateSecurityGroupRequest securityGroupRequest = new CreateSecurityGroupRequest(SECURITY_GROUP, "DDI DDS Security Group Process");
        securityGroup = ec2.createSecurityGroup(securityGroupRequest);
        LOG.debug(String.format("Security group created: [%s]", securityGroup.getGroupId()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.debug("Cannot Create Security Group " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

When trying to locate the security group

```
DescribeSecurityGroupsRequest request
                    = new DescribeSecurityGroupsRequest().withGroupNames(this.SECURITY_GROUP);

            DescribeSecurityGroupsResult response
                    = ec2.describeSecurityGroups(request);

            for (SecurityGroup group : response.getSecurityGroups()) {
                System.out.printf(
                        "Found security group with id %s, "
                        + "vpc id %s "
                        + "and description %s",
                        group.getGroupId(),
                        group.getVpcId(),
                        group.getDescription());
                secgrp = group;
            }
```

I get the following error message

```
The security group 'SECURITY_GROUP_NAME' does not exist in default VPC 'vpc-107a0555' (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidGroup.NotFound; Request ID: e283089b-187f-410e-8b93-b78c92fac3c6)
```

Maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.700</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sts</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.701</version>
</dependency>
```

Any thoughts as to why this happens?
Regards
Konteh

Comment: How much time elapses between creating the security group and retrieving it? Much of AWS is eventually consistent, which means that it might not be available immediately.

Comment: BTW, your dependencies are incorrect (or at least sub-optimal). The first one will pull in all of the (200+) SDK JARs, which you almost certainly don't want. The second pulls in the STS JAR, which doesn't have anything to do with security groups.

Comment: @Parsifal okay I'll seek to optimize the maven dependencies. I'm using a lot of other aws features as well. Okay, I wasn't waiting or sleeping between creation and retrieval, so sounds like I should add logic to wait for the security group to be created. The only thing is that it appears to have never been created in the aws interface when this occurs.